# What is a Real Number?

Tags: real-analysis, definition

I believe I'm over thinking it, but I want to be 100% sure.

A Real Number is any number, correct?  Whether it be an integer or something else.

It's the set $\mathbb R$ from $(-\infty, +\infty)$ correct?

Comment: Well, not really. i is a number, but isn't a real number. Also, it's vague what you are saying. Reals numbers are defined as having the obvious properties of rational numbers, but with one added axiom called completeness.

Comment: @simplicity : But $i$ is not in the interval $(-\infty,+\infty)$.

Comment: where does i lie?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A common way to think about the real numbers as the set of every point on the number line between $-\infty$ and $+\infty$, including irrational numbers (like $\sqrt{2}$) and transcendental numbers (like $\pi$ and $e$).

For most people this is totally sufficient, though this doesn't really come close to telling you what they *are*, and it's circular anyway (how do you define the number line..?)

Perhaps a more illuminating way to think about the real numbers is as the rational numbers (i.e. the numbers of the form $p/q$ for $p,q$ integers and $q\neq 0$) with all of the 'gaps' filled in. In fact, that's the layman's description of one of the formal ways of specifying the real numbers -- as the *completion* of the rationals.

When we say that the rationals aren't complete, we mean that there are sequences of rational numbers that converge to (get closer and closer to) a number that isn't a rational. The sequence

$$\frac{1}{1}, \frac{14}{10},  \frac{141}{100}, \frac{1414}{1000}, \dots$$

is an example of such a sequence -- every number in the sequence is rational, but the *limit* is the irrational number $\sqrt{2}$.

This can't happen with the real numbers, because 'all the gaps are filled in'. Every sequence of real numbers that converges is guaranteed to converge to a real number.

Comment: You might want to add that the bulk of the real numbers are numbers that you can't actually define in anyway. Indescribable numbers.

Comment: Thanks, a very detailed and informative explanation!

Comment: "Every sequence of real numbers that converges is guaranteed to converge to a real number" - maybe a better phrasing is every cauchy sequence is convergent, you can't say "Every sequence of real numbers that converges" since if $\sqrt{2}$ is 'not there' the sequence you havw in your answer (is cauchy) not convergent

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the integers and fractions are real numbers, as are things that [cannot be expressed as fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrational_number), such as $\sqrt 2$ and $\pi$. That is, the real numbers means the entire [number line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_line). On the other hand, $\infty$ and $-\infty$ are not real numbers.

The reason they are called "real numbers" as opposed to simply "numbers" is that higher mathematics works with various other kinds of things we call "numbers" too -- but those things do not correspond to points on the number line. You can safely ignore this until you need to learn about [complex numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number) (or transfinite [ordinal numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number), or [cardinal numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number), or [p-adic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number) or whatever).

Answer (score 4):

It seems most people are complicating the answer you are looking for.

Yes, you are correct, it is the set of all numbers on the number line, i.e any number in (-∞, +∞).

Comment: That's not true. If you don't assume completeness you will get every number in the number line. But, with bits missing out like irrational numbers.

Comment: If you ask yourself what is the number line, you'll see this is self-referential.

Comment: @AdamZalcman: It doesn't matter. The OP is not asking for a definition, only clarification, so it is permitted to be self-referential. (Just like dictionary entries often are circular if you follow them deep enough, but still help in our understanding of a term.)

Answer (score 2):

You can think of the set of real numbers as the set of all rational numbers closed under taking the limits of Cauchy sequences, i.e. all rational numbers plus all limits of Cauchy sequences you can build in the set.

However, not all numbers belong to the set of real numbers, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number.

Comment: You can argue that complex numbers aren't numbers. I personally see complex numbers as just matrices. Which, in my view aren't numbers.

Comment: That's semantics, not mathematics.

Comment: @simplicity: You might consider a new moniker. (Yes, I am aware of matrix representations of complex numbers and quaternions)

Comment: @ChrisTaylor well, semantics in this case are important. Surreal numbers, hyperreals, ordinal numbers.

Comment: @simplicity: We already know which algebraic structure we're in, so there is no possibility of confusion with other notions of number and your point about semantics does not obtain. Moreover, as Henning states in chat, you yourself called $i$ a "number" in your first comment to the question. Ultimately, mathematics at this sort of level all boils down to study of various algebraic structures, wherein the ones most closely connected with the original notions of numbers and the trending generalizations thereof receive the label of number.

Comment: Some might argue that real numbers aren't numbers. They might see real numbers as just series. Which, in their view wouldn't be numbers.

Comment: @AdamZalcman Who cares what computer scientist think? or them crazy intuitionist mathematician. I suppose you can argue that only natural numbers are true numbers.

Comment: @simplicity: Without a non-arbitrary definition of "true numbers${}^{\mathrm{(TM)}}$" to go by it'd be nothing but hot air.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition is a bit loose...See this link for a more accurate definition and some examples:

[Link-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number)